# Refactoring the processing of Mysql query to PHP side

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query I'm using in my CodeIgniter model to fetch the count of listings of products between particular days. What this query is doing is it's taking status_from from logs where the date is during and after the selected date range and taking added_date from listings where the date falls before the from date range picked by the user and calculates it. Once it has retrieved those records, it checks the table for what variable that status holds and does a `sum(case when else 0)` to get the total count.

```
function get_report(){
 $sql = with Y as (
  with recursive D (n, day) as (
    select 1 as n, '2021-09-25' my_date
    union
    select n+1, day + interval 1 day from D
      where day + interval 1 day < '2021-10-15'
  ) select * from D
), X as (
  select Y.day,
         l.*,
         (select status_from from logs
            where logs.refno = l.refno
              and logs.logtime >= Y.day
            order by logs.logtime
            limit 1) logstat
    from listings l, Y
    where l.added_date <= Y.day
), Z as (
  select X.day, ifnull(X.logstat,X.status) stat_day, count(*) cnt
    from X
    group by X.day, stat_day
)
select Z.day,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'D' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Draft,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'A' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Action,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'Y' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Publish,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'S' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Sold,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'L' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Let
  from Z
  group by Z.day
  order by Z.day;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query;
}
```

Dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6789f0517b194b09d235860dc794ea14

Now here as you can see I'm processing my calculations in the sql statement itself, but I want to do these calculations in my php side, basically iterating everytime it encounters `Z.stat_day = 'D'` then adding 1 to Draft column and same for the other statuses.

Current View Class:

```
<?php
            foreach($data_total as $row ){
               $draft = $row->draft ? $row->draft : 0;
               $publish = $row->publish ? $row->publish : 0;
               $action = $row->action ? $row->action : 0;
               $sold = $row->sold ? $row->sold : 0;
               $let = $row->let ? $row->let : 0;                              
          ?>
              <tr>
                    <td><?= $row->day?></td>
                    <td><?= $draft ?></td>
                    <td><?= $publish ?></td>
                    <td><?= $action ?></td>
                    <td><?= $sold ?></td>
                    <td><?= $let ?></td>
              </tr>
          <?php }  ?>
```

Basically I want to refractor my PHP code to do the same thing the Mysql statement is doing, but keeping the query simple and all processing in the PHP side for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Start by pre-building a permanent table with a list of "days" going far into the future.  Index it on day.  Then use it that table in place of `Y`.

Instead of

```
from listings l, Y
where l.added_date <= Y.day
```

you probably want

```
FROM Y
LEFT JOIN listings AS l  ON l.added date = Y.day

WHERE Y.day BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

That way days that are missing from `listings` will be shown in the output.  However values will show as `NULL`, so you may want something like `COALESCE(col, 0)` instead of `NULL`.

Are you trying to get "cumulative" subtotals?  (cf `l.added_date <= Y.day`)  If so, you need to look at the "windowing" functions of 8.0; they will probably be much faster.  (Are you using 8.0?)